# Isomorphism between homotopy groups of CW-complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes, higher-homotopy-groups

Let $(Y, y_0)$ and $(Y’, y_0)$ pointed CW-complexes, with $Y’$ obtained from $Y$ by attaching $n+1$-cells. Why is it true that $i_{*}: \pi_{q}(Y, y_0) \to \pi_{q}(Y’, y_0)$ is an isomorphism for $q < n$ and an epimorphism for $q=n$?
I am aware of the fact that this is true if $Y$ is the $n$-skeleton of $Y’$, but here I only know that the $n$-skeleton of $Y’$ is contained in $Y$. By the way, this has already been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086201/attaching-cells-gives-isomorphism-of-homotopy-groups), but I couldn’t quite understand the answer.

As a related question: if $e_{\alpha}^{n+1}$ is a $n+1$-cell in $Y’$, why is it true that $i_{*}(\alpha) =0$?

Note I am using notation as in Switzer, Lemma 9.8 in the chapter dedicated to Brown theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By cellular approximation, up to homotopy, one may assume that $Y'$ is obtained by adding $n+1$-cells to the $n$-skeleton of $Y$, so that $Y^{(n)}= Y'^{(n)}$

Let $f:S^q\to Y'$ be a pointed map, $q\leq n$. Then by cellular approximation, up to pointed homotopy, $f$ lands in the $n$-skeleton of $Y'$. But the $n$-skeleton of $Y'$ is the same as that of $Y$, so $f$ lands in $Y$ up to homotopy. This shows surjectivity for $q\leq n$.

Similarly, if $q<n$, because then $q+1\leq n$,  again by cellular approximation, any homotopy between two such maps can be homotoped to live in $Y$, and so this shows injectivity for $q<n$.

For the second question, if you've added a cell along $\alpha: S^n\to Y$, then that means, *by definition*, that there is a commutative diagram :

$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD} S^n @>>> Y\\
@VVV @VVV \\
D^{n+1} @>>> Y'\end{CD}$

it follows that $S^n\to Y\to Y'$ extends to $D^{n+1}$, i.e. it is $0$ in homotopy.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was helpful. I have a couple of questions though: when you say that up to homotopy we can assume that $Y'$ is obtained by attaching $n+1$ cells to $Y^{(n)}$, are you secretly using cellular approximation theorem? Could you please detail this assumption a little bit? Also, what do you say about my second question on $i_{*}(\alpha) = 0$?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I use, let me edit that in ! The point is that if $f, g: S^n\to Y$ are homotopic, then adding $f$ or adding $g$ results in homotopy equivalent spaces. For the second question, the point is just that you're literally adding a cell along $\alpha$, so it dies in $\pi_n$ by definition

Comment: Thank you! One last question: is this commutative diagram a homotopy pushout?

Comment: It's a pushout and a homotopy pushout, yes